# Struct array as input parameter

Tags: c#

I have a struct in my class called RangeName and in one method I am setting up an array of this as follows:

```
RangeName[] myNames = new RangeName[currWkb.Names.Count];
```

and later on I want to pass myNames into another method. I have tried:

```
public void TestRoutine(RangeName[] myNames)
```

but my code will not build. I get

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'MyTools.clsTest.RangeName[]' is less accessible than method 'MyTools.clsTest.TestRoutine(MyTools.clsTest.RangeName[])'

Comment: Post the code of `RangeName`, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your  `RangeName` struct `public` (at least). Structs and classes are `internal` by default.Or ofcourse you can make your method less accessible by making it `internal`.

Comment: "Structs and classes are internal by default": almost. That's true for top-level types (class, struct, interface). But not for nested types. In general, default accessibility is the most restrictive accessibility which still leaves the declared member usable. For nested members, including types, that accessibility is actually `private`, not `internal`.

Answer (score 2):

When you get an inconsistent accessibility error, it means that a method with higher accessibility (in this case, that would be `public`) has a parameter type of low accessibility.

You need to ensure that the `RangeName` struct has public accessibility in its enclosing context. Locate the declaration, and add `public` in front of `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

Your RangeName struct is of a lower accessibility than your public TestRoutine which takes RangeName[] as a parameter. If anyone tried to call TestRoutine they would never be able to pass in a parameter as that struct has a very high chance of being inaccessible to the caller.

You can fix this by either making your TestRoutine a lower or equal accessibility to RangeName or increasing RangeName to public.